# STS 3.6.4 CodeSet 'initial': Can't use 'Maven': There is no 'pom.xml'

Tags: spring, maven

When I import Spring getting started content, and then choose Consuming Rest Android it shows error : CodeSet 'initial': Can't use 'Maven': There is no 'pom.xml'

I do not have maven installed, in stead use the embedded maven that comes with STS (3.2.1 embedded). I see, it creates a .m2 folder under my user, and even downloads the jars, when I selected create spring starter project from the Dashboard.

Not sure, why its saying CodeSet 'initial': Can't use 'Maven': There is no 'pom.xml'.

I even deleted the m2 folder, and tried, no luck. Where is it trying to find a pom.xml ?

Comment: The pom.xml file has to been located in the root folder of your eclipse project

Comment: But in this case, I have not created any project, because the getting started project SHOULD ideally download everything and create a project in STS, that's what is said.